# how to create a database from a class with multiple class inside

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a model which i need create a table and database from it, but the problem is my class is nested:

```
public  class PaymentModel
{
    public string CreditorName { get; set; } = default!;
    public CreditorAccounts CreditorAccount { get; set; } = default!;
    public DebtorAccounts DebtorAccount { get; set; } = default!;
    public InstructedAmounts InstructedAmount { get; set; } = default!;
    public string RemittanceInformationUnstructured { get; set; } = default!;
    public class CreditorAccounts
    {

        public string Iban { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Currency { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public class DebtorAccounts
    {

        public string Iban { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Currency { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public class InstructedAmounts
    {
        public string Currency { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Amount { get; set; } = default!;
    }
    public class PaymentAccounts
    {
        public string Iban { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Currency { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public class PaymentAmounts
    {
        public string Currency { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Amount { get; set; } = default!;
    }

}
```

whats the best practice here?should create a table for each class?and join them?or there is a better way to create  a single table ?

Comment: Most would recommend Entity Framework (to include myself), but if you want to do it the manual way, you are correct that the best approach is to create a table per class, adding primary keys and foreign keys to create what's referred to as a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i strongly suggest use entity framework if you have knowledge.
You should create a table for each classes that provide easy control and makes it more developable on future if you need.
You do not have to join them. Create your tables like;

CreditorName: Id(int), CreditorName.
CreditorAccount: Id(int), CreditorId(int), Iban, Currency

You can reach all data connected with creditorname by CreditorId.